# How can I limit a specific resource to a cargo wagon?

Tags: factorio

I have a train station that loads iron into a train for export, and imports coal from a different train. I have this problem where iron is being loaded into the coal train. Is there a way I can place a logistics filter on the wagon to stop iron from coming in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can restrict the slots of the coal cargo wagon to only allow coal (middle-click by default). If it already contains coal, it won't even ask what should go into that slot.

In the newest version trains can be blueprinted, so you might even be able to make a blueprint of the cargo wagon with the restricted slots, and make copies with already-restricted slots. But I haven't tried this since train blueprints are rather new.

Comment: Awesome, I knew there must have been some way to do it, thanks

Comment: Even without blueprints, you can ctrl+c to copy a wagon that's set up the way you want and ctrl+v to paste that configuration on another wagon